# How to setMap(), setVisible() 4000/5000 of markers without losing performance in Google maps api V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing lot of performance issues first while loading **4000/5000** markers on map and then showing /hiding 1000 of markers.

Both **setMap()** and **setVisible()** work slowly for me. Sometimes browser is also getting crashed.

However, I have seen many websites using Google maps api V3 which load many markers seamlessly. So I can't compromise on speed.

Does anyone has any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

With this amount of markers, you need to use a marker clustering technique or Fusion Table.

There is a nice article from Google here with the solutions you can use:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to push the limits of the JJWDesign Google Maps Package for SugarCRM. 5,000 markers seems to map easily. I begin to see performance issues when trying to map 25,000+. But, I think it greatly differs between browsers. I've seen horrible performance on older IE browsers (IE6). Google Chrome seems to have the best performance.

Below is a video of mapping 5000+ Leads from SugarCRM. Note, the Leads are pre-geocoded by the Google Geocoding API. Data is transferred into the view via JSON.

Google Maps Demo of 5000+ Leads Mapped within SugarCRM:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPbRV0aLia4

You can view the main Javascript functions on this page:

GitHub.com Porject:

https://github.com/jjwdesign/JJWDesign-Google-Maps/blob/master/SugarModules/modules/jjwg_Maps/views/view.map_markers.php

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding markers in html page.I too had similar issue when load 1000 markers on html page itself. this is because may be you are using loop to add marker in html page.  try to add markers in angular. this will speed the process and now i am able to load 20000+ markers

```
$scope.map_function = function(){


homeService.homemapdata($scope.dummy).success(function(data){

 $scope.all_device_location=data.all_device_location;
 $scope.map_center = data.map_center;




  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(cities[0]['latitude'],cities[0]['longitude']);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [
        {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.locality',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#263c3f'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#2f3948'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.station',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        }
      ],

    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);


  // Geo Location /
    // navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    //     // map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(mapcenter[0]['latitude'],mapcenter[0]['longitude']));
    //     var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
    //         position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,
    //     pos.coords.longitude),
    //         map: map,
    //         icon: {
    //           path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
    //           scale: 3
    //         },
    //         // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    //         title: "My Location"
    //     });
    // });
    bounds  = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    $scope.map = map;
    // Additional Markers //
    $scope.markers = [];
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var createMarker = function (info){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.latitude, info.longitude),
            map: $scope.map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,


        });
        loc = new google.maps.LatLng(info.latitude, info.longitude);
        bounds.extend(loc);
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.device_user__name + '</div>';
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + info.device__device_name + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });
        $scope.markers.push(marker);
    }  
    for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
        createMarker(cities[i]);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);


        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, $scope.markers, { maxZoom: 20});
         $scope.location_loading=false;

        }, 1);



 });
}
```